# Handlebars each loop not working despite all other objects working just fine

Tags: json, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, hbs

I have a section of an application which:

- Makes an API call to send a JSON object back to the client. One of the properties of this JSON object is a simple array of strings.
- Uses handlebars.compile to display this data back to the user.

Here is the object I'm working with:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("7867867868786786786786786"),
  title: 'rgfregre',
  description: '',
  createdBy: '6687678786786786',
  cards: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  createdAt: 2021-10-31T02:59:31.496Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-10-31T02:59:31.496Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

and here is the Handlebars code:

```
    <script id="pack-modal" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="title">\{{title}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pack-modal-body">
            <label for="description" class="description-label">Description (optional):</label>
            <textarea name="description" class="pack-description"></textarea>
            <div style="height: 500px;">
            {{#each cards}}
            <h1>??</h1>
            {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    </script>
```

And the JS code although it probably isn't any use here

```
async function openPackModal(packInfo) {
    try {
        const data = await fetch('/get-pack', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ "pack": packInfo }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });

        const result = await data.json();
        console.log(result);

        const packModalScript = Handlebars.compile(packModalTemplate);
        const html = packModalScript(result);
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
        displayModal();
        addCloseModal();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I can access everything else absolutely fine, title, createdAt etc, but the cards each loop simply will not work. I can even replace {{title}} with {{cards}} and get [1, 2, 3] as a H1 so I know handlebars has access to it.  I've added the CDN for the latest version of handlebars as well. I have to add the \ in front of title & everything else to get it to work, but doing it with the cards loop throws an error. I have no clue why this isn't working.

Comment: Throws an Error? What is the Error?

Comment: The `\{{title}}` bit concerns me. The starting slash is an escape character and the way you are using it suggests to me that your template is being compiled by Handlebars twice - perhaps once on the server and once on the client.

Comment: @76484 Well, not so much throws an error. But the content you're trying to provide just isn't there at compile time without the escape character. I know I read somewhere that if you use something or do something in your code you need the escape character. I can't remember what it was or where I read it though. I'm only building a prototype of something at the moment anyway. I doubt I'll use Handlebars for any real projects.

Comment: Does your HTML source have the `{{#each cards}}` or not?

Comment: Only the script tag included above uses the each loop right now.

Comment: What I am trying to confirm is if your template script element is being interpolated on the server before it is sent to the client. That's why I am asking if the `{{#each cards}}` is present in the HTML response or if it is missing.

Comment: It's missing. Nothing shows up at all where the each loop should be adding content.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the fact that you are using Handlebars on both the server and the client.

You are running a node app using Express and using express-handlebars as the view engine. This means that all of your HTML markup - including `<script>` tags - is in Handlebars templates that are getting executed and interpolated before being sent to the client as an HTTP response.

Your client-side code is also using Handlebars to create HTML snippets from asynchronously-loaded data. The markup for these templates is located in your `<script>` tags. The problem is that the Handlebars syntax in these templates has already been executed by your server-side, express-handlebars view engine.

This is why you have had to prefix your `{{title}}` express with a slash, `\`. This is telling the server-side Handlebars to *ignore* interpolation of the `{{title}}` expression and render it in its raw form, `{{title}}`.

Similarly, you could do the same with your `#each` call, as in:

```
\{{#each cards}}
  <h1>??</h1>
\{{/each}}
```

If you find adding all of these slashes to be tedious, Handlebars provides support for [Raw Blocks](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#raw-blocks). Raw Blocks will allow you to add a helper to output blocks of template in their raw, uninterpolated form.

First, you would register the helper where you configure your express-handlebars view engine. For example:

```
exphbs.create({
  helpers: {
    raw: function () { return options.fn(); }
  }
});
```

And then you can use this helper in your templates by wrapping it around blocks that are to remain raw (note the quadruple mustache syntax):

```
<script id="pack-modal" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{{{raw}}}}
    {{title}}
    {{#each cards}}
      <h1>??</h1>
    {{/each}}
  {{{{/raw}}}}
</script>
```

This will render everything between the `{{{{raw}}}}` tags as it written, removing the need for the `\` prefix before every Handlebars expression.

Comment: I appreciate the help and the long answer. But I'd tried the \{{each}} before I posted this question and it didn't work. Again, thank you, but I've decided since, I'm probably going to change the entire html and get rid of pack-modal. There's not really much point in trying to resolve the issue now.